# Display images from another origin in Angular web application

Tags: html, angular, image

I have an angular application that can display youtube videos via a popup window. To open the popup window, the user has to press on a youtube thumbnail image. This thumbnail image is requested using the following url: `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/<youtube video id>/1.jpg` for instance https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zOnQbryNQJE/1.jpg.

This image is displayed *just fine* when i'm running the app locally on my computer.

But as soon as I serve the application from a cloudfront distribution, the image generated with `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zOnQbryNQJE/1.jpg` is no longer displayed. but shows a broken image file icon where the thumbnail image should be.

The annoying part is that the `networks` tab of `Chrome` does not even display the request to `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zOnQbryNQJE/1.jpg` as if the request was never made in the first place. Image requests coming from the same origin are displayed correctly.

I've tried using the `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute but that has no effect. Its not just the youtube image that won't display when the app isn't running locally, the problem occurs when using *any* image from the web that comes from a different origin.

My code looks like this:

```
<img loading="lazy" crossorigin="anonymous" (load) = "journalEntryImage.imageLoading = false" (error)="journalEntryImage.imageLoading = false; journalEntryImage.addYoutubePlayIconToThumbnail = false" [src]="journalEntryImage.thumbnailImageUrl" [alt]="journalEntryImage.id" class="centerCropImage product-image clickable" (click)="showFullImageDialog(journalEntryImage)" />
```

I've tried removing `loading=lazy` to see if that made any difference which it didn't. How do i display images from another website in my angular webapplication?

EDIT:

I also tried using `[src]=sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(urlString)`
but this causes a loop where the youtube image url isn't requested but `www.wqeqwvst2.cloudfront.net/null`. The statuscode is `304`. I have no idea what its doing.

Comment: have you tried sanitizing the url? using Sanitizer from Angular

Comment: @Andres2142 i was just looking into that :)

Comment: Can you put your code into stackblitz?

Comment: How about you leave angular aside and try with simple <img /> tag? I mean it's a web page, so it should be able to render an img tag. If it can render an image tag or at least show some hint in network tab, then the problem comes from the angular app, not the image host. If a simple html page cannot display your image then the problem comes from the image host.

Answer (score 0):

import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

constructor(
private sanitizer : DomSanitizer
){
}

try img tag with src="{{URL}}"

in Angular

this.URL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(//define URL in here and if you stuck in cache you can add any word to url like this '?date=' + new Date)